# how can I run updating each component with Pulumi

Tags: pulumi

I'm using pulumi, but I have a problem.
for example, if I use terraform, I would do this:

```
cd terraform/component/${componentName}
terraform workspace new dev
terraform workspace select dev
terraform init -input=true -reconfigre -backend-config "bucket=${bucket_name}" -backend-config "profile=${profile_name}"
terraform apply dev.tfvars
```

in that cases, in Pulumi, how can I specify script file to update?

even if I update pulumi, index.ts will be invoked.

I wont to specify script file path to update.
folder structure is like here.

```
src/
    components
        lambda
            main.ts
        ec2
            main.ts
```

in this cases, I want to run something like this.

```
pulumi up src/components/ec2/main.ts
pulumi up src/components/lambda/main.ts
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think you can do something like this with pulumi, it looks for the main.ts in the local folder. What you can do - is create a config parameter in your code and use that to define which code path pulumi will take (I'm using python, but the idea is the same):

```
if (config.get("parameter_name") == "path_one"):
    call_function_from_file_1
else:
    call_function_from_file_2
```